# V4L2 driver memset and print different?

Tags: c, module, kernel, v4l2

I am currently developing a V4L2 driver for a custom camera sensor we are building and I am facing an issue that I do not understand.
To put some context,

- The image is written by an FPGA in a reserved memory region that contains to 4 buffers.
- I have a first class (p3v4l2cam) that listen to a registered IRQ provided by the system to indicate when an image is ready and start a tasklet to read the image and store it in an output buffer queue.
- The FPGA also changes the value of a register that tell me which buffer is currently used (with an index from 0 to 3).
- I am running at 60 FPS for the moment.
- To check the consistency of the buffer indexes, I read the index in the register and I fill the buffer with a value corresponding to the index using a memset

This is the relevant part of the code

```
    //Fill the buffer
    buf->filled = 0;
    buf->buffer_idx = ioread32(p3v4l2fg.ctrldev->ctrl_regs.vaddr + CURRENT_BUFFER_IDX) >> 29;

    buf->jiffies = jiffies;
    buf->frame_time = ktime_get_ns();

    // Fill the buffer with the value of the buffer index
    memset(data, buf->buffer_idx, p3v4l2fg.singleBufferImSize);

    // Print the info in the logs
    PRINT_INFO("%d %d\n", counter, buf->buffer_idx);
    counter++;
```

The **data** variable is create using a kmalloc.

When I look at the value printed in the log through dmesg, I have this as an output:

```
[16620.170969] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 972 0
[16620.185995] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 973 1
[16620.201021] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 974 2
[16620.216047] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 975 3
[16620.231081] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 976 0
[16620.246108] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 977 1
[16620.261132] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 978 2
[16620.276162] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 979 3
[16620.291196] P3V4L2,/home/root/p3-modules/p3v4l2/p3v4l2cam.c(p3v4l2_fg_tasklet_fn):103 -> 980 0
```

Two numbers are visible, the first one is the frame number and the second is the buffer index.
This is produced by the PRINT_INFO in the code part I show above. The succession of buffer indices in this case is valid. The time between two prints (being an estimate of the time between two interrupts) is valid and corresponds to the expected frame rate (~ 15 ms).
However, the problem arises when I look at the recorded image (which corresponds to the output of memset). The succession is not good. It is as if I missed some buffers. For example, the corresponding buffers index in the recorded images are:

```
972: 1
973: 2
974: 3
975: 0
976: 2
977: 3
978: 0
979: 1
980: 2
```

It is very obscured to me where the issue could come from?
Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Yours,

Pi-r

Comment: Maybe other thread is updating buf->buffer_idx while memsetting?

Comment: This is in a tasklet and it is the only one piece of code that writes in the buffer. From my (poor) understanding, this could therefore not be possible.

Comment: in the log, the first frame number is 972 and the buffer index is 0  However, in the recorded images the frame number is 972 and the buffer index is 1.   This is a very strong indication of a timing issue.

Comment: Thank you. This shift in index appears at one point. From my understanding, this is related to the fact that memset is taking to much time (1280*480 bytes at 60 frames per second). It seems to me that this should not be the case...